# Reversing instructions using R

Tags: r

Is it possible to reverse this following instructions?

```
PSG.list <- searchTwitter('#PSG', n=2000, cainfo="cacert.pem")  
PSG.df = twListToDF(PSG.list) 
write.csv(PSG.df, file='CSV/Fr/PSGTweets.csv', row.names=F)
```

I deleted the variable PSG.list after saving the csv file, but now i need it because it is a parameter in a function.

Thank you.

Comment: can you share a few sample rows of PSG.df

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
dat <- read.csv('CSV/Fr/PSGTweets.csv')

dat$text <- as.character(dat$text)
dat$favoriteCount <- as.numeric(dat$favoriteCount)
dat$replyToSN <- as.character(dat$replyToSN)
dat$created <- as.POSIXct(dat$created)
dat$replyToSID <- as.character(dat$replyToSID)
dat$id <- as.character(dat$id)
dat$replyToUID <- as.character(dat$replyToUID)
dat$statusSource <- as.character(dat$statusSource)
dat$screenName <- as.character(dat$screenName)
dat$retweetCount <- as.numeric(dat$retweetCount)
dat$longitude <- as.character(dat$longitude)
dat$latitude <- as.character(dat$latitude)

n<-nrow(dat)
PSG.list=list() 
for (i in 1:n){ 
  PSG.list[i] = statusFactory$new(dat[i,])
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mikalai. Check out the `stringsAsFactors` and `colClasses` arguments in `?read.csv`.  You could greatly reduce the code in your answer.

Comment: Thanks @GSee! Indeed it is better to use `dat <- read.csv('PSGTweets.csv', as.is = TRUE)`